# Valgrind running on PowerPc does not report any leaks?

Tags: valgrind

Downloaded the latest version, Valgrind 3.7.0, untarred it to create a folder "Valgrind-3.7.0"
Now, what I did was export gcc for compatibility with the target machine and configured to disable tls and give the host. 
Also I made a C Program "leak.c" and its object file "a.out" compiled with the following command

```
export CC=/usr/local/netd_tools_v1/powerpc/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc leak.c
```

so

```
a.  export CC=/usr/local/netd_tools_v1/powerpc/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc
b.  ./configure --prefix=/netd --host=powerpc-linux --disable-tls 
c.      make
d.      make install
```

- Link the library path and valgrind executable
  (go to /netd/lib and do
  ln –s /u/netd/lib/valgrind THEN 
  goto /netd/usr/sbin and 
  do ln –s /u/netd/bin/valgrind)
  Some files were made in "Valgrind-3.7.0" and a folder "netd" was formed.
  "netd" contained "lib", "bin", "share" and "include"

(/netd/lib  and /netd/usr/sbin are project specific directories)

Copied these files (files in "netd") into the Target Machine and ran Valgrind on the file "a.out" by the following command :

```
valgrind --log-file=/u/july5.txt --leak-check=summary --tool=memcheck ./a.out
```

(`/u` is the mount point, `july5` is the log file)

The output shows 0 leaks reported

```
     int main()
     {
     printf("I am leaking.");
     int *a =(int *) malloc(100);
     return 0;
     }
```

This ran on linux just fine and reported memory leaks.
If this would have worked, then I would have run Valgrind on project specific processes.

Output of Log File on LINUX for a.out:

```
[asaini@OTN05 abhaysaini]$ vi xyz.txt

    ==14843== Memcheck, a memory error detector

    ==14843== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==14843== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==14843== Command: ./a.out
    ==14843== Parent PID: 51

61
==14843==
==14843==
==14843== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14843==     in use at exit: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==14843==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 100 bytes allocated
==14843==
==14843== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14843==    definitely lost: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==14843==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14843==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14843==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14843==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14843== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14843==
==14843== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14843== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

OUTPUT of Log File on PowerPc

```
[00002003-Unknown] Debug> cat leak.txt
==1208== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1208== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1208== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1208== Command: ./a.out
==1208== Parent PID: 1195
==1208==
--1208-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--1208-- When reading debug info from /lib/ld-2.3.2.so:
--1208-- Can't make sense of .data section mapping
--1208-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--1208-- When reading debug info from /u/Leak/a.out:
--1208-- Can't make sense of .data section mapping
--1208-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--1208-- When reading debug info from /u/netd/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-ppc32-linux.so:
--1208-- Can't make sense of .eh_frame section mapping
==1208== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==1208==    at 0x4011E08: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4016517: ???
==1208==    by 0x400917F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4005083: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4006967: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4002C0F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400DF03: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4001BD3: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400215F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400EF2B: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==
--1208-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--1208-- When reading debug info from /u/netd/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-ppc32-linux.so:
--1208-- Can't make sense of .eh_frame section mapping
--1208-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--1208-- When reading debug info from /lib/libc-2.3.2.so:
--1208-- Can't make sense of .data section mapping
==1208== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==1208==    at 0x4011CC0: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x7: ???
==1208==    by 0x400AB33: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4002ECB: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400DF03: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4001BD3: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400215F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400EF2B: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==
==1208== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==1208==    at 0x4011D38: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x7: ???
==1208==    by 0x400AB33: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4002ECB: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400DF03: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4001BD3: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400215F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400EF2B: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==
==1208== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==1208==    at 0x4011D64: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x7: ???
==1208==    by 0x400AB33: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4002ECB: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400DF03: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x4001BD3: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400215F: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0x400EF2B: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==
==1208== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==1208==    at 0x400B958: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0xFE8ABE7: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0xFE7278B: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==1208==

... snip ...

==1208==
==1208== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==1208==    at 0x400BBE0: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0xFE8ABE7: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0xFE7278B: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==1208==
==1208== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==1208==    at 0x400BB0C: ??? (in /lib/ld-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0xFE8ABE7: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==1208==    by 0xFE7278B: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==1208==
==1208==
==1208== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1208==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1208==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==1208==
==1208== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1208==
==1208== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1208== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1208== ERROR SUMMARY: 40 errors from 20 contexts (suppressed: 3908 from 442)
```

Error (after trying the patch in the link https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=290066 : (by iWerner)

```
[00002003-Unknown] Debug> cat 1.txt
==1134== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1134== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1134== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1134== Command: ./Leak/a.out
==1134== Parent PID: 1071
==1134==

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld.so.1
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld.so.1
valgrind:
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing leak.c (if it's short)?

Comment: int main()
        {
        printf("I am leaking.");
        int *a =(int *) malloc(100);
        return 0;
        }

Comment: Something's wrong in you r post, because your second Linux log also shows `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible`
I'd start by looking into solving the `WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info`. Apparently Valgrind can't read the debug info from the `a.out`, so first of all you should check the

Comment: sorry, now the correct post is there. I executed the same file  (a.out) on linux and powerpc but i got leak report when i ran it on linux. 
The command I used to compile the file on linux is written below :
[B]gcc leak.c (Compiled) [/B]

valgrind --log-file=/home/abhaysaini/xyz.txt ./a.out (Executed)

Output of xyz.txt for linux, Steps of compilation and execution for PowerPc are already shown above. 


Kindly let me know why Valgrind is showing 0 memory leaks instead of 1 memory leak of 100 bytes for PowerPc?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Valgrind. The `WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info` is the clue.
Apparently, [you're not the only one that has these problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=valgrind+can't+make+sense+of+.data+section+mapping)

Comment: I tried the patch given on that link. After using that, we got a different error. 
That is added after the ""OUTPUT of Log File on PowerPc".